# bash ** differs from zsh **, can we change bash behavior?

Tags: bash, zsh, wildcards

I have this files tree:

```
a.py
b/c.py
```

In Bash, `ls -l **/*.py` gives

```
b/c.py
```

In Zsh, `ls -l **/*.py` gives a nice

```
a.py
b/c.py
```

Is there a way to change bash behavior to avoid doing `ls *.py **/*.py` ?

PS: I used `ls` but the question is for any command

Comment: Presumably in bash you have the `globstar` option unset (check with `shopt globstar`), making `**/*.py` equivalent to `*/*.py` ?

Comment: See also `set -o globstarshort` in `zsh` to further align zsh and `bash -O globstar`, where `**` then does the same as `**/*` like in `bash -O globstar` though note that while `**.py` then becomes the same as `**/*.py` (a bit like in `fish`), that's still the same as `*.py` in `bash`.

Comment: start bash with `bash -O globstar` works but is it possible to activate this option in a running shell (i am in a docker script)

Comment: yes @steeldriver the option is off

Comment: `shopt -s globstar` to enable within `bash`.

Comment: See also [The result of ls \* , ls \*\* and ls \*\*\*](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/62660)

Comment: Perfect @StéphaneChazelas, exactly what if need. Could you move this to an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In plain sh and shells that are backward-compatible with plain sh, the patterns `**` and `*` are equivalent. Zsh deviates from sh compatibility in a few ways, one of which is that the patterns `**/` and `***/` do [recursive globbing](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing). `**/…` searches the current directory, its subdirectories, its subsubdirectories, etc. `***/…` is similar, but also traverses symbolic links to subdirectories.

You can enable a similar feature in bash ≥4.3 with [`shopt -s globstar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin), in ksh93 with `set -o globstar` / `set -G`. Other related options are:

- `shopt -s dotglob` to make wildcard patterns match dot files (similar to `set -o dotglob` / `globdots` in zsh).

  - setting the `GLOBIGNORE` variable in `bash` also enables that option automatically¹.
  - You can achieve a similar effect in ksh93 with `FIGNORE=.:..`.
  - In zsh, this can also be done on a case-by-case basis with the glob qualifier `(D)` after the pattern. Bash / ksh93 have no similar feature.
- `shopt -s extglob` to enable ksh88-style extended glob operators (similar to `set -o kshglob` in zsh) (always on in ksh).

  - zsh also has `set -o extendedglob` which is an alternative way of expressing arbitrary regular expressions (with a negation operator) with a different syntax. Bash has no equivalent of that syntax.
- `shopt -s nocaseglob` to make pattern matching case-insensitive (similar to `set -o nocaseglob` / `set +o caseglob` in zsh).

  - In zsh, this can be done on a case-by-case basis by prefixing the pattern with `(#i)`. In ksh93, similarly, you can prefix the pattern with `~(i)`. Bash has no similar feature.
- `shopt -s nullglob` to make glob patterns expand to an empty list if no file matches, instead of leaving the pattern unchanged (similar to `set -o nullglob` in zsh).

  - In zsh, this can be done on a case-by-case basis with the glob qualifier `(N)` after the pattern. In ksh93, put `~(N)` before the pattern. Bash has no similar feature.
- `shopt -s failglob` to trigger an error if no file matches, instead of leaving the pattern unchanged (default behavior in zsh).
- `set -o globstarshort` in `zsh` makes `**` behave like `**/*`. For instance, your `**/*.py` could then also be written `**.py`. In `bash -O globstar`, `**` alone is similar to `**/*` (except that `dir/**` includes `dir/` in its expansion), but `**.py` is the same as `*.py`.

Bash 4.0 introduced the `globstar` option and the `**` pattern, but beware that before bash 4.3, it always traverses symbolic links to directories, and before 5.0 traverses *some* symbolic links. Bash 3.x and below has no such feature.

Similar forms of recursive globbing are also available in the `tcsh`, `yash` and `fish` shells (not enabled by default).

---

<sup>¹ beware there are some differences between those shells when it comes to the `.` and `..` special directories. They are never expanded by `zsh` globs, setting `FIGNORE=.:..` excludes them in ksh93, but in bash they are excluded from globs such as `*` even with `dotglob`, but not from the `.*` ones. Setting `GLOBIGNORE=.:..` helps for `.*`, but not for `dir/.*` or `.*/file`.</sup>